# Android. Whats the difference between ShapeDrawable and GradientDrawable?

Tags: android, shapedrawable

I'm new to Android dev and have a little confusion about ShapeDrawable and GradientDrawable classes. What's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

The shape defines a shape like rectangle, oval, line or ring. The gradient is used to define what the shape will look like. You can have a shape filled with a solid color for example or with a gradient.

Comment: How can I add a gradient to a ShapeDrawable object?